# "BindException: Address already in use" after an application is quited

Tags: java

I am learning to code microservices in VertX on my new MacBook, and here is the issue:

1. I wrote some code, which builds http server at localhost, port 8080, and named it MyMicroservice.
2. I ran it (succesfully) with command java -jar MyMicroservice.
3. I quit it using ctrl+z.
4. I try to run it again, in the same way - and I get:
   [INFO] SEVERE: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

How to avoid it? I can handle it with restarting my computer, but I believe there are is some faster approach?

Comment: You should try Ctrl-C instead of Ctrl-Z.

Comment: With Ctrl Z you do not kill the service that is binded to the port 8080 so when you are trying to re-connect to that port with a new service you get this error. You can check which processes are on port 8080 via this command 

`lsof -i:8080`

then you can kill the processes listed with 

`kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, to find and kill the process that is listening to a specified port (often 8080)

1. Open the Command Prompt as Administrator
2. netstat -anbo | findstr "8080"

Note: must use double quotes

The last field in the response line is the process id (pid). 
Stop the process with

3. taskkill /F /PID pid

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Daniu** and **NickAth**, as you said the problem was wrong command - ctrl+z just suspended the process, and ctrl+c kills it, what works here fine.